# LenovoY700 Windows 10 BSODs and keyboard shutting down

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, bsod

i was looking for help with my LenovoY700 running Windows 10. Some days it's working good but the other days my keyboard just stops working(can't even put laptop to sleep), it is literally off. Only thing i can do i press Power button for couple of seconds to shut it down completely. In this time system and mouse is working completely normal and i can do everything that doesn't include using keyboard for like 5-15 minutes and then im getting BSOD. I tried analysing minidump and updated wifi drives and intel integrated graphics card drivers but that wasn't it :(

[Minidump file download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B17JSMJjuugYV3ZnZjhlMVhpTGs)

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17336 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\121216-31234-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*C:\Windows\symbol_cache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 8 Kernel Version 14393 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 14393.447.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.161102-0100
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`8028f000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`80594060
Debug session time: Mon Dec 12 01:22:44.612 2016 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 1 days 10:41:32.400
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
...
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
................
Cannot read PEB32 from WOW64 TEB32 0000df8f - Win32 error 0n30
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 9F, {3, ffffbe8841188060, ffff800136f9c8e0, ffffbe8841a0a010}

Probably caused by : pci.sys

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffbe8841188060, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: ffff800136f9c8e0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffbe8841a0a010, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x8
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5801a742

MODULE_NAME: pci

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80379510000 pci

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17336 (debuggers(dbg).150226-1500) amd64fre

DPC_STACK_BASE:  FFFF800136FA4FB0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffff8001`36f9c8a8 fffff800`8048a1cf : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffbe88`41188060 ffff8001`36f9c8e0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffff8001`36f9c8b0 fffff800`8048a0e2 : ffffbe88`41a0b4c8 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000004 ffffbe88`41a0b540 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xeb
ffff8001`36f9c910 fffff800`802f2300 : ffffbe88`00000000 ffffbe88`41a0b500 00000000`00140001 00000000`00000002 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x22
ffff8001`36f9c960 fffff800`803dc59a : 00000000`00000000 ffff8001`36f6d180 ffff8001`36f79bc0 ffffbe88`42df2680 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x440
ffff8001`36f9cbe0 00000000`00000000 : ffff8001`36f9d000 ffff8001`36f96000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.14393.351

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_ACPI_IMAGE_pci.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_ACPI_IMAGE_pci.sys

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_acpi_image_pci.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {20ddeb92-07eb-ebdc-bd08-44da71ffbd68}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: Does this crash happen while in Safe Mode?

Comment: I don't know. Somedays it is working for like a week without a problem and the other days i can get this problem like 3 times a day. Can happen even in browser but when i do get that i think it is mostly when entering or exiting a game.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the dmp shows that the device "`VEN_8086&DEV_1901`" (*Intel(R) Xeon(R) E3 - 1200/1500 v5/6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) PCIe Controller*) casues the crash:

```
2: kd> !podev ffffbe8841188060
Device object is for:
  DriverObject 41a90a70
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000022 AttachedDev ffffbe883ce774b0 DevFlags 00001040
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffbe88411887b0:
PowerFlags: 00000040 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=4
Dope: 00000000:
2: kd> !devstack ffffbe8841188060
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffbe8841a1cb10  \Driver\pci        ffffbe8841a1cc60  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffbe8841a1cae0

  ffffbe883ce774b0  \Driver\ACPI       ffffbe883ceeb840  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffbe883ce77480

> ffffbe8841188060  \Driver\pci        ffffbe88411881b0  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffbe8841a34d30 :
  DeviceInst is "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1901&SUBSYS_380217AA&REV_07\3&11583659&0&08"
  ServiceName is "pci"
```

So a device inside the laptop caused it. Update all drivers (nVIDIA GPU, Intel HD, wireless, LAN, Sound) and [disable power saving options of the PCIe Bus in Power](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/292971-pcie-link-state-power-management-turn-off-windows.html) settings and look what happens.